# Why does gcc, with -O3, unnecessarily clear a local ARM NEON array?

Tags: c, gcc, arm64, neon, compiler-bug

Consider the following code ([Compiler Explorer link](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEEgEADqgKhE4MHt6%2B/qRJKY4CIWGRLDFxXAF2mA5pQgRMxAQZPn4VmPb5DLX1BIUR0bHxtnUNTVkVwz2hfSUD5QCUtqhexMjsHOYAzKHI3lgA1CYbbvUsAPphAgB0CIfYJhoAgvcPAG6oeOh7UV7AEKEEAA5TgQ9gAqJYEUh7NAMBQg/5AkGg0JzA4Adisjz22L2/GIez%2Bgj2eAOGwAInsNIcLMTSW49mZqcTrNZUSYMc8cVziYIAaouAA2VSSYF7VTU56c7nY1SXF5iEwAVgsVMVFMOFJetHQXAAjqcFACIOYBaElRZBWDmWq5hKsdKxXKFcquEr1eTHfLaObGWrSRTZV7zRs3f69i8FAhiPqGAajYHnSq3VC0baNpinvbpRGCJJ9YbjWYBRDzQLJFa8MmxWmM1z2WTJWiyRwFrROIreH4OFpSKhOG4WZY9golitMAczBseKQCJoWwsANYgKeXAFFtGSLgATi3AsnG0VRf0nEkvBYEg0GlIXZ7fY4vAUICvs%2B7LdIcFgSDQLASdFi5Eob9f3oOITjLYAuC4S8%2BDoAhYkfCAojnUgolCeoAE9OGnb82EEAB5BhaEw19SCwFhDGAcQSPwYgqkcF5MEfEjMFUKovDgrDeH%2BNpkNoPAomIDCPCwTiZ2IPBz24N8qAMYAFAANTwTAAHc8ISRhRP4QQRDEdgpBkQRFBUdQSN0Lh9AolBBxsPiokfSAFlQBIOiYgBaPCNgfNo6LSFwGHcTxmj0YIpmKUo9FyVIBFGPxzMijpejC2ZbG86oBC6EZAqyczKjSzoJkS/oyiGboYr0OFukKmYygWEdllWPQCFotYeFbdtO2Qu8HgAJQAWTLPZgGQZA9kgy4uAJAdLGsKFcEIEgJynKEPB/P98U2Lg5l4F8tDmRdl0kVcNh3MxJAFNENEkDYp0VAVjw4U9SHPKCrxvXg7wfJ8ZznBYP0QFBUFWkCAIgIC1pAE4XgBVydgoyCNHMmhaDg4gEKQkjUOYYhiOwwHcIIAiiOQsiKKonsaJ8himJ7Fi2I4qTyEEHiSNswTseEtYeyaiTOIWGSmDkxSVLUjSGa04RRHEfTxaMtRkN0AIDCMKzpssfR%2BPsiBHOctI3I8rz2l8iBXDK8yQqKIqIuSKL0iy2KcmthLQstnLUo6DLGjt8q3ZqArneq8qJlNkqGiq8LNsWeq9LEzAWrfNsOA7a9Os4SHoaYaEleAUauEuDRxsm6zZvwIh1sncy9hW4DYkWswtu%2B189tIJdrsua7247zv7set7e04T7nx%2BtqODMDqSI%2BhvdoWBjUd8yQgA%3D%3D%3D)), compiled under gcc and clang with `-O3` optimization:

```c
#include <arm_neon.h>

void bug(int8_t *out, const int8_t *in) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        int8x16x4_t x;

        x.val[0] = vld1q_s8(&in[16 * i]);
        x.val[1] = x.val[2] = x.val[3] = vshrq_n_s8(x.val[0], 7);

        vst4q_s8(&out[64 * i], x);
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: this is a minimally reproducible version of an issue that is popping up in many different functions of my actual, much more complex code, filled with arithmetic/logical/permutation instructions performing a totally different operation from above. Please refrain from criticizing and/or suggesting different ways of doing what the code above does, unless it has an effect on the code generation issue discussed below.

clang generates sane code:

```armasm
bug(signed char*, signed char const*):                            // @bug(signed char*, signed char const*)
        ldr     q0, [x1]
        sshr    v1.16b, v0.16b, #7
        mov     v2.16b, v1.16b
        mov     v3.16b, v1.16b
        st4     { v0.16b, v1.16b, v2.16b, v3.16b }, [x0], #64
        ldr     q0, [x1, #16]
        sshr    v1.16b, v0.16b, #7
        mov     v2.16b, v1.16b
        mov     v3.16b, v1.16b
        st4     { v0.16b, v1.16b, v2.16b, v3.16b }, [x0]
        ret
```

As for gcc, it inserts a lot of unnecessary operations, apparently zeroing out the registers that will be eventually input to the `st4` instruction:

```armasm
bug(signed char*, signed char const*):
        sub     sp, sp, #128
        # mov     x9, 0
        # mov     x8, 0
        # mov     x7, 0
        # mov     x6, 0
        # mov     x5, 0
        # mov     x4, 0
        # mov     x3, 0
        # stp     x9, x8, [sp]
        # mov     x2, 0
        # stp     x7, x6, [sp, 16]
        # stp     x5, x4, [sp, 32]
        # str     x3, [sp, 48]
        ldr     q0, [x1]
        # stp     x2, x9, [sp, 56]
        # stp     x8, x7, [sp, 72]
        sshr    v4.16b, v0.16b, 7
        # str     q0, [sp]
        # ld1     {v0.16b - v3.16b}, [sp]
        # stp     x6, x5, [sp, 88]
        mov     v1.16b, v4.16b
        # stp     x4, x3, [sp, 104]
        mov     v2.16b, v4.16b
        # str     x2, [sp, 120]
        mov     v3.16b, v4.16b
        st4     {v0.16b - v3.16b}, [x0], 64
        ### ldr     q4, [x1, 16]
        ### add     x1, sp, 64
        ### str     q4, [sp, 64]
        sshr    v4.16b, v4.16b, 7
        ### ld1     {v0.16b - v3.16b}, [x1]
        mov     v1.16b, v4.16b
        mov     v2.16b, v4.16b
        mov     v3.16b, v4.16b
        st4     {v0.16b - v3.16b}, [x0]
        add     sp, sp, 128
        ret
```

I manually prefixed with `#` all instructions that could be safely taken out, without affecting the result of the function.

In addition, the instructions prefixed with `###` perform an unnecessary trip to memory and back (and anyway, the `mov` instructions following `### ld1 ...` overwrite 3 out of 4 registers loaded by that `ld1` instruction), and could be replaced by a single load straight to `v0.16b` -- and the `sshr` instruction in the middle of the block would then use `v0.16b` as its source register.

As far as I know, `x`, being a local variable, can be used unitialized; and even if it weren't, all registers are properly initialized, so there's no point in zeroing them out just to immediately overwrite them with values.

I'm inclined to think this is a gcc bug, but before reporting it, I'm curious if I missed something. Maybe there's a compilation flag, an `__attribute__` or something else that I could to make `gcc` generate sane code.

Thus, my question: is there anything I can do to generate sane code, or is this a bug I need to report to gcc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code generation on a fairly current development version of gcc appears to have improved immensely, at least for this case.

After installing the [`gcc-snapshot`](http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/universe/g/gcc-snapshot/gcc-snapshot_20210918-1ubuntu1_arm64.deb) package (dated 20210918), gcc generates the following code:

```
bug:
        ldr     q5, [x1]
        sshr    v4.16b, v5.16b, 7
        mov     v0.16b, v5.16b
        mov     v1.16b, v4.16b
        mov     v2.16b, v4.16b
        mov     v3.16b, v4.16b
        st4     {v0.16b - v3.16b}, [x0], 64
        ldr     q4, [x1, 16]
        mov     v0.16b, v4.16b
        sshr    v4.16b, v4.16b, 7
        mov     v1.16b, v4.16b
        mov     v2.16b, v4.16b
        mov     v3.16b, v4.16b
        st4     {v0.16b - v3.16b}, [x0]
        ret
```

Not ideal yet -- at least two `mov` instruction could be removed per iteration by changing the destination registers of `ldr` and `sshr`, but considerably better than before.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: welcome to GCC. Do not bother optimizing anything while you are using it. And Clang isn't better either.

Secret tip: Add ARM and ARM64 components to Visual Studio, and you'd be surprised how well it works. The problem is however, it generates COFF binary, not ELF, and I haven't been able to find a converter.

You can use Ida Pro or dumpbin and generate a disassembly file and it look. like:

```
; void __fastcall bug(char *out, const char *in)
                 EXPORT bug
bug
                 MOV             W10, #0
                 MOV             W9, #0

$LL4                                    ; CODE XREF: bug+30↓j
                 ADD             X8, X1, W9,SXTW
                 ADD             W9, W9, #0x10
                 CMP             W9, #0x20 ; ' '
                 LD1             {V0.16B}, [X8]
                 ADD             X8, X0, W10,SXTW
                 ADD             W10, W10, #0x40 ; '@'
                 SSHR            V1.16B, V0.16B, #7
                 MOV             V2.16B, V1.16B
                 MOV             V3.16B, V1.16B
                 ST4             {V0.16B-V3.16B}, [X8]
                 B.LT            $LL4
                 RET
; End of function bug
```

You can copy paste the disassembly to a GCC assembly file.

And don't bother with reporting the "bug" either. If they were listening, GCC wouldn't be this bad in first place.

Comment: Just to be clear - the first paragraph is targeted at ARM + Neon audience, not stating a general assumption about GCC / Clang across all of their supported fields, correct?

Comment: @Fureeish it's not a general assumption, but sharing decades long experiences.

Comment: Regarding ARM + Neon, or claiming that it applies to wider field? What I am trying to say is that I'd completely disagree with such statement if it were to be targeted at modern x86-64 targets. Also backed by long experiences (not only mine).

Comment: @Fureeish ARM, and especially NEON. I won't argue about x68 since I fortunately don't have to deal with it. Neon intrinsic has been around for over ten years, and GCC is still unusable. That's a fact. People should be aware of that. PS: I don't see any `x86` tag here.